# Java String to Map. Best way to do that

Tags: java, regex, string, dictionary, bnd

Hi I have a problem that I can't solve. A have exported pacakges from the jar manifest in form of String and I want to put it in Map where key is the name of the package and the rest information in **value**. You will say that is peace of cake but lets show you what exactly I want to do. I have a String, I little piece from it

```
 aQute.bnd.annotation;version="1.43.1",aQute.bnd.annotati
 on.component;version="1.43.1",aQute.bnd.annotation.metatype;version="1.
 43.1",aQute.bnd.ant;uses:="aQute.service.reporter,org.apache.tools.ant,
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs,org.apache.tools.ant.types";version="0.0.
 0",aQute.bnd.build;version="2.1.0";uses:="aQute.bnd.maven.support,aQute
 .bnd.osgi,aQute.bnd.service,aQute.bnd.service.action,aQute.bnd.version,
 aQute.service.reporter",aQute.bnd.build.model;version="2.3";uses:="aQut
 e.bnd.build.model.clauses,aQute.bnd.properties,aQute.bnd.version,org.os
 gi.resource",aQute.bnd.build.model.clauses;version=2;uses:="aQute.bnd.h
 eader",aQute.bnd.build.model.conversions;uses:="aQute.bnd.build.model,a
 Qute.bnd.build.model.clauses,aQute.bnd.header,aQute.libg.tuple,org.osgi
 .resource";version="0.0.0"
```

If I split it on comma(,) in the keys there will be wrong peaces because we have

```
aQute.bnd.ant;uses:="aQute.service.reporter,org.apache.tools.ant,
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs,org.apache.tools.ant.types";version="0.0.
 0"
```

where in **uses** clause we separate the name of the dependent packs with comma too. So the line above have to be in my output map as:

```
Key: aQute.bnd.ant
Value: uses:="aQute.service.reporter,org.apache.tools.ant,
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs,org.apache.tools.ant.types";version="0.0.
 0"
```

So which String methods or regex to use to do my work?

Comment: can you specified the desired sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//split at , only if it's not within ""
String[] packages=input.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")+[^\"]*$)");
for(String pack:packages)
{
    String[] output=pack.split("(?=uses:=)");
    output[0];//key
    if(output.length==2)//incase if there's no value
    output[1];//value
}
```

---

**Edit**

`(?=uses:=)` is a lookahead which would match at the position which is followed by `uses:=`..Now we could have used `uses:=` as regex but that would eat `uses:=`...To avoid it we use [zero width lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: no problem but I don't understand fully the logic what __?=__ means.

Comment: @Xelian have a look at [zero width lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the long way is the easiest way:

```
public static Map<String, String> parse(String s) {
    Map<String, String> allPackageInfo = new HashMap<>();

    CharacterIterator i = new StringCharacterIterator(s);
    char c = i.first();
    while (c != CharacterIterator.DONE) {
        StringBuilder packageName = new StringBuilder();
        while (c != ';' && c != CharacterIterator.DONE) {
            packageName.append(c);
            c = i.next();
        }

        if (c == ';') {
            c = i.next();
        }

        StringBuilder packageInfo = new StringBuilder();
        while (c != ',' && c != CharacterIterator.DONE) {
            if (c == '"') {
                do {
                    packageInfo.append(c);
                    c = i.next();
                } while (c != '"');
            }
            packageInfo.append(c);
            c = i.next();
        }

        if (c == ',') {
            c = i.next();
        }

        allPackageInfo.put(packageName.toString(), packageInfo.toString());
    }

    return allPackageInfo;
}
```